# same table update from previous quarter row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a daily stock transaction table
`T1(symbol, transDate, closingPrice, PrevQtrChange)`.

The last column is empty.  I need an update statement that, for a given symbol, will get the closing price from the previous quarters transaction.  Because of weekends, holidays, etc, i can't do a self join on the date being date-90 days.  I could do it with a cursor, but ugh.  And, the table contains millions of rows, so a cursor would be extremely slow, even with an index.

I'm a C/C++ programmer so while I know some SQL, doing this efficiently is something I'm unsure of.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide sample data and expected output*

Comment: Please define which logic you want to match dates across quartes. All quarters do not have the same number of days.

Comment: You probably just want a calendar table that explicitly enumerates every date (including leap years and bank holidays, etc), then assign each day to an explicit quarter, or each date to a corresponding date "one quarter ago".  Populating that becomes the headache, mostly by code but with some possible manual adjustments, but using that calendar table becomes trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions.  The idea for the previous price is:

```
select t.*,
       last_value(closingPrice) over
            (partition by symbol
             order by transDate
             range between unbounded preceding and interval 90 day preceding
            ) as prev_quarterprice
from t;
```

You can then incorporate this into an `update`:

```
update t join
       (select t.*,
               last_value(closingPrice) over
                    (partition by symbol
                     order by transDate
                     range between unbounded preceding and interval 90 day preceding
                    ) as prev_quarterprice
        from t
       ) tt
       on tt.symbol = t.symbol and tt.transDate = t.transDate
    set t.PrevQtrChange = closingprice - tt.prev_quarterprice
    where tt.PrevQtrChange is null ;
```